# HOW TO ORDER BY WITH SPECIFIC CONDITION IN SQL

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

```
Name    | count  
jaison    23  
Drew      45  
Abd       22  
Ricky     55  
OTHERS    10
```

I'm looking to order by the count from higher to Lower and leaving the OTHERS at the bottom of the table in SQL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`,  `SQL Server,`  etc...) that you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Simple enough using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT Name,Count
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Name='OTHERS' THEN -1000 ELSE Count END desc
```

(Assuming `Count` cannot be negative, which it shouldn't be for any plain meaning of that word)

---

(I would normally link `CASE` above to specific documentation. Without knowing which SQL product you're using however, I'll leave it to you to look up documentation on it if you need more information about it)

Answer (score 0):

You should use two keys instead of magical values:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (case when name = 'Others' then 1 else 0 end),  -- put Others last,
         count desc;
```

Ironically, in your case `'Others'` already has the lowest value, so:

```
order by count desc
```

does what you want.